# How to get kerberos Ticket to access Solr : Error: Unspecified GSS failure

Tags: node.js, kerberos, spnego

I have written a **NodeJS script** which must connect a **Solr API** securised with **Kerberos**.

So I used the **krb5 package** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/krb5) to wrapp the **kinit** command like that to get the token to access the Solr API :

```
var krb5 = require('krb5');

krb5.kinit({
  principal: 'my-username@mydomain',
  password: 'my-password'
}).then(function (ccname) {
  console.log('Credentials saved in', ccname);
  return krb5.spnego({
    service_fqdn: 'HTTP@my-application-fqdn',
        service_principal: 'my-application-name'
  })
}).then(function (token) {
  console.log('SPNEGO token :', token)
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log('Erreur :',err)
})
```

After executed, the script returns :

> Credentials saved in /tmp/krb5cc_1002
>
> **Erreur : Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (minor 100001)**

I don't understand the error. I tried to search the translation of the 100001 code but I found nothing.

Comment: A decent GSSAPI binding would produce the error label, not a numeric code (binary? octal? decimal?)

Comment: Note that even with a label, you are far from a diagnostic -- see for example https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/errors.html (with the Java implementation)

Comment: Side note: I don't understand what you stuff into the "FQDN" and "principal" variables. A Kerberos service principal (SPN) is built like `service-type/hostname-fqdn@KERBEROS.REALM` and I never saw SPNego using any other "service-type" than `HTTP`

Comment: Bref. Le snippet dans la documentation du module JS est raisonnable -- et FQDN signifie _fully qualified domain name_ => le nom complet DNS du serveur, rien d'autre.

Comment: I tried with service_fqdn: 'my-application-fqdn' but it's not better